# Django ManyToMany with inheritance

Tags: django, inheritance, many-to-many

I've checked a number of SO articles and I don't believe there is any way to accomplish what I want to do, but before I abandon Django I wanted to articulate the question itself and see if I missed something.

I'm implementing a graph (nodes, edges) which can contain subclasses of a base type.  That is, an edge can connect a base class to a subclass, or a subclass to a subclass, etc . . .   I want to be able to pull all the edges for a given object, find the objects these edges point to, and call some function on these terminal objects.  I was hoping that I could call the function in a polymorphic way, but I can't figure out a way to make that happen.

```
class Node(models.Model):
    ...
    def dosomething():

class SpecialNode(Node):
    ...
    def dosomething():

class Edge(models.Model):
    #yes, related_name is weird, but this seems to be what makes sense
    source = models.ForeignKey(Node, related_name='targets')
    target = models.ForeignKey(Node, related_name='sources')
```

With this structure I can do:

```
sourceedges = node.sources.all()
for sourceedge in sourceedges:
    sourceedge.source.dosomething()
```

But the "dosomething" function is always called on the Node object, even if source is actually a SpecialNode object.

I've tried doing this with django_polymorphic but I don't believe this supports M2M inheritance through an Edge object (this is required for other reasons in my app).

I've tried to use contenttypes, but I think you're only allowed one generic relation per class.  Edge, in other words, can't have 2 different generic relations in it.

I imagine I could establish an object called an Endpoint which would have just a single generic relation on it, then link the Edge object to it like so:

```
class Endpoint(models.Model)
    ...
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey(...)

class Edge(models.Model)
    source = models.ForeignKey(Endpoint, related_name='targets')
    target = models.ForeignKey(Endpoint, related_name='sources')
```

But this introduces another level of indirection in my model and I start to feel like the framework is coding me rather than the other way around :)

Anyway, if someone has figured out a way to get this particular use case done, please let me know.  A better way than what I suggested above would be welcome, as I currently like a lot of things I get out of the box with Django.

Thanks

Comment: So `source = models.ForeignKey(SpecialNode, related_name='targets')` also calls `Node's dosomething()` you mean?

Comment: No, that works.  But I'm not sure that sources will always be SpecialNodes.  They may be Nodes.

Comment: Why not create two abstract base classes, one for each type? Then you can just invoke one of them as a Mixin in whatever model you want.

Comment: Not sure I understand how that would work.  I want my Node object and my SpecialNode object to behave differently when I call the same function in them (dosomething).  The idea is that once I have an Edge, I can just get whatever is on the end of it and call that function.  How would I do that with a Mixin?